# Can't get bash to loop in chef

Tags: bash, unix, chef-infra, chef-recipe

I am trying to run a loop over array in chef (The loop contains a bash command). Anyone has any idea on this ?

```
symlink_db = data_bag_item(“my”_db,”my”_db)
source = symlink_db[“sourceFile”]
instances = symlink_db["Instances"].split(',')  <---Instances is a comma separated string in Databag

bash "create_link" do
   puts "1: #{instances}"       <-------Puts all instances correctly
   instances.each do |instance|
        puts "2: #{instance}"    <------ This prints each instance in loop correctly 

        code <<-EOH           
           echo "ln -fs #{source} #{instance}";   <----- This is printed only for last instance in the loop
        EOH
        end
end
```

Appreciate if anyone can help soon.....Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need the bash resource inside your loop:

```
instances.each do |instance|
  bash "create_link-#{instance}" do
    code <<-EOH
      echo "ln -fs #{source} #{instance}"
    EOH
  end
end
```

BTW, this is not idiomatic chef. You should simply use the `link` resource like this:

```
instances.each do |instance|
  link instance do
    to source
  end
end
```

An advantage of this approach is that it makes your recipe cross-platform. It's also a lot more readable.